# Access .NET 4.5 DLL from 2.0 Application

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2013, gac

We have upgraded one application to .NET 4.5.2 Framework, and also we have some older application built in .NET 2.0.

The issue here is, the 2.0 Application cannot find the 4.5 dlls which is under the new GAC (%windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly). I think 2.0 application still looks in old GAC.

Please suggest some solutions. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Recompile your 2.0 application to .Net 4.5 (4.0 would be enough). Or make your 2.0 application run under the CLR of .Net 4.5 by adding the following to your application's config.

```
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152935(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I am still looking for solution to this problem. I am not the owner of the 2.0 application, so cant upgrade to 4.0. That 2.0 application using our 4.5 dll's previously thru the GAC. now since the GAC location changed, that application cannot access our 4.5 dlls'

Comment: Have you tried my solution? Does it work? If not, then what is the error?

Comment: I tried your solution, but since I am not able to add the reference of 4.5 dll directly in Visual studio, it fails. so I guess we have to add a codebase tag in app.config file as below.                                    <runtime>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Main.test.sample" publicKeyToken="e922e3fd683b3777" culture="neutral"/>
    <codeBase version="4.3.0.467" href="C:/sample-4.3_Portable_32bit/sampple_4.3.0.467/Main.test.sample.dll"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
</runtime>        but still its throwing a runtime error saying file not found

Comment: and also its able to load 4.5 dll using reflection, but I cant change the 2.0 application code at this point. so need a solution with config file or so.